# Can't find "hosted" mode in Theia

Tags: theia

1. I built the IDE with instructions in https://www.theia-ide.org/doc/Composing_Applications.html and it worked.
2. Then I followed the instructions given in https://www.theia-ide.org/doc/Authoring_Plugins.html. I was able to build one of the Sample plugins but when I go to test it, I am not able to find the "hosted" mode in the IDE I built in #1 -- I looked at "Find Command" and searched for "hosted" with no results
3. Here is the config info from "Help->About"

   @theia/core 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/output 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/process 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/filesystem 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/variable-resolver 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/workspace 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/languages 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/editor 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/navigator 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/markers 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/outline-view 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/monaco 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/callhierarchy 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/typescript 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/terminal 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/json 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/userstorage 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/preferences 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/messages 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/git 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/file-search 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/mini-browser 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/preview 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/merge-conflicts 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/search-in-workspace 0.5.0-next.8968ac21
   @theia/textmate-grammars 0.5.0-next.8968ac21

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks!
Dildar

Answer (score 1):

You should add `@theia/plugin-ext` to enable Theia plugins or `@theia/plugin-ext-vscode` to enable VS Code extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@theia/plugin-dev` and `@theia/plugin-ext` to package.json and **try to find the command in web page** rather than local IDE.

Which means, you should start another Theia application first. Then press F1 key to find `>hosted plugin: start Instance` command on http://localhost:3000/.

This will let you select the path of "theia-hello-world-plugin" folder and then open another page http://localhost:3030/.